# React native got blank screen

Tags: react-native, navigator

I'm new to react-native, and I'm trying to use a navigator to switch between different scenes. However, when the simulator runs, instead of printing an error, I just got an empty, blank, white screen that shows nothing expect the remaining battery, the time, and the wifi signal. I checked my code many times and cannot find an error. Can someone help me on this?

This is my index.ios.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import Chatroom from './Views/Chatroom';
import Chat from './Views/Chat';

class goals extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <Navigator
        initialRoute={{screen: 'Chatroom'}}
  renderScene={(route, nav) => {return this.renderScene(route.screen)}}
  />
)
  }

  renderScene(route,nav) {
switch (route.screen) {
  case 'Chatroom':
    return <Chatroom navigator={nav} />
  case 'Chat':
    return <Chat navigator={nav} />
      }
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('goals', () => goals);
```

This is my Chat.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is  chat</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.gochatroom.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to chatroom</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }


  gochatroom() {
    this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'Chatroom' });
  }
}
```

This is my Chatroom.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class Chatroom extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is chatroom</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.gochat.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to chat</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }


  gochat() {
    this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'Chat' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the right arguments to `renderScene`. The following should work better:

```
renderScene={(route, nav) => this.renderScene(route, nav)}
```